# Field containing emoji, showing unicode on querying

Tags: visualforce, salesforce-classic

I am having a custom field in which I'm storing text and emojis but when I am querying the record its giving unicode character for ex: **`&#127885;`** instead of .

I have already used `EncodingUtil.URLENCODE(str,'UTF-8')` and `EncodingUtil.URLDECODE(str,'UTF-8')` but of no use. Please help me with this

Comment: No, as he is already getting the emojis on page load.

Comment: Database is text based, it will only store its unicode value and show you. Even the tool you use to querry if it does not support emoji , you would still see the code.

Comment: What is the field type of your custom field? What code are you using to retrieve and display the content?

Comment: @DavidReed I am using just a long textarea type of field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this one, I just needed to append `unescapeHtml4()` in the string I am showing on the page.

Earlier it was :

```
String varForVF = objInstance.fieldHavingEmoji;
```

Corrected one :

```
String varForVF = objInstance.fieldHavingEmoji.unescapeHtml4();
```

Now It works fine and I am able to see the emojis on the VFPage.

Comment: Although I had to follow what @oleksandrberehovskyi had suggested because on page rerender emojis were shown like small boxes.

Comment: And thanks everyone for your quick replies.